# Which framework/package provides the file dialog which is used by a lot of gnome applications?

Tags: gnome, launchpad, bug-reporting

I want to file an odd behavior of the file dialog which is shared by a lot of GNOME applications (`evince`, `gedit`, etc.) when the user opens or saves files as bug in launchpad. I was wondering which what would be the right component/package for that. I'm using the "Ambiance" theme in `unity` on Ubuntu 14.10.

I could just file the bug for the program where I last experienced the issue, but that seems wrong and in case the maintainer isn't so nice to change the component, the issue will just expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a part of the [GTK+ toolkit](http://www.gtk.org/). File a bug for the package `libgtk-3-0`